# What does the code "DECLDIR __declspec(dllexport)" really do?

Tags: c, file, dll

```
#ifndef _DLL_TUTORIAL_H_
#define _DLL_TUTORIAL_H_
#include <iostream>

#if defined DLL_EXPORT
#define DECLDIR __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DECLDIR __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C"
{
   DECLDIR int Add( int a, int b );
   DECLDIR void Function( void );
}

#endif
```

What does the code `DECLDIR __declspec(dllexport)` really do?

Comment: @deepak: Welcome to `StackOverflow`! I formatted your code (select it and press Ctrl+K).

Answer (score 9):

In the Microsoft world, `__declspec(dllexport)` makes a function or class callable from outside the DLL.

When you create a DLL, by default, any functions defined within the DLL are only callable from that same DLL.  You cannot call that function from an executable or a different DLL.

If you want your a function to be called from outside the DLL, you need to export it by adding `__declspec(dllexport)`.

One way to think about it is that `__declspec(dllexport)` marks a function as being part of a DLL's public interface.

While you didn't ask about `__declspec(dllimport)` that is sort of the opposite.  When calling a function in a different DLL, your DLL needs to know that it's part of a different DLL's public interface so it can properly handle the call (calling a function in a different DLL requires more complex code that calling a function in yourself).

Comment: Thanks  for such nice and easy explaination

Answer (score 1):

It defines the `DECLDIR` macro constant to be `__declspec(dllexport)`. `dllexport` is for exporting functions from DLLs. Here's a quote from [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2.aspx):

> These attributes explicitly define the
>   DLL's interface to its client, which
>   can be the executable file or another
>   DLL. Declaring functions as dllexport
>   eliminates the need for a
>   module-definition (.DEF) file, at
>   least with respect to the
>   specification of exported functions.
>   Note that dllexport replaces the
>   __export keyword.
>
> If a class is marked
>   declspec(dllexport), any
>   specializations of class templates in
>   the class hierarchy are implicitly
>   marked as declspec(dllexport). This
>   means templates are explicitly
>   instantiated and its members must be
>   defined.

`__declspec`, by the way, is [explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dabb5z75%28VS.80%29.aspx).